# Is there any web player that supports Google/On2's VP8 Video (VP80)

Tags: jwplayer, vp8

I have to play video, that parameters are:

- audio: Vorbis Audio (vorb)
- video: Google/On2's VP8 Video (VP80)

I tried to use JWPlayer, but unsuccessfully. Is something wrong with video or there is any other web player that support VP80?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead and try this one [DarkOnyx](http://darkonyx.web-anatomy.com) - I'm using this on my site for like 2 weeks and it's brilliant. For encoding videos I suggest [Miroconverter](http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/). It generates nice WEBM (VP8) and OGV (tehora) video from MP4. Just sometimes when MP4 is messed up it may not work (be aware of that).

Answer (score 0):

KMPlaer, (any M Player ), and VLC also offers play back supportability to VP8 ( Container --webM, MKV ) with (Audio codec -- vorbis )

In android VLC Beta, MXPlayer .